# Seems I need to repeat date_default_timezone_set() each time I need to work with dates withing the same script

Tags: php, time, timezone

So, there is either something I don't understand, or sometime broken somewhere.

To my understanding, when I set date_default_timezone_set, it's supposed to work for the entire current script. But working with one this morning, nothing seemed to work, up until I started to call date_default_timezone_set before *each* call to, for example, a date() or strtotime() function within the same script/file.

I don't particularly want to change the php.ini file directly, I like to keep it to UTC by default. I just want to set the timezome for the script being run, but I don't want to have the call to date_default_timezone_set on almost every other lines!

Can anybody confirm that it's (or isn't) normal behavior and how I could try to resolve this?

**EDIT**:

Here is an example of what I need to to in order to have times correctly.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Montreal');
$hour_from =  get_field('hour_from', $v->ID);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Montreal');
$hour_to =  get_field('hour_to', $v->ID);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Montreal');
$hour_from_norm = strtotime($hour_from);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Montreal');
$hour_to_norm = strtotime($hour_to);
```

Comment: You can set it in a header file that you would include in every other file. That way you only call it once (so to speak) and outside the scripts you're working on.

Comment: @Bono I just edited the question so there is an example, I actually need to make the call multiple time per files.

Comment: You only need to set in once. Are you sure that your `get_field()` method is not messing with the time-zone?

Comment: @joren I am. Although, at this point I'm retrying everything line by line, to make sure it's allright.

Comment: @joren I found the culprit. I was using a file from wordpress to hook to one site's database, turns out Wordpress do mess with default time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I was using a file coming from Wordpress somewhere, and didn't expect it to be reseting time zone to UTC. But it did.

Searching line by line after @joren confirmed I should have to set it only once got me to the right track to discovery. Thank you!